# How to save `git diff` to terminal result when I exit `git diff`?

Tags: git

When I run `git diff`, I get this:
`

```
diff --git a/gllue/common/dataimport/synccandidateimport.py b/gllue/common/dataimport/synccandidateimport.py
index f6d18c8..86cf6d9 100644
--- a/gllue/common/dataimport/synccandidateimport.py
+++ b/gllue/common/dataimport/synccandidateimport.py
@@ -302,6 +302,7 @@ class SyncCandidateImport(CandidateDataImport):

     def process_default_value(self, column):
         now = datetime.datetime.now()
+        hello world
         buildin_fields_map = {field: now for field in self.buildin_fields}
         default_value = self.default_value_map.get(column.field,
                                                    buildin_fields_map.get(column.field.name))
```

`

When I quit `git diff`, this information will disappear in the end , how do I change the order after exiting the `git diff`, I can still see the information out of the top of the terminal .

- List item

Answer (score 1):

Many git commands use pager, you can easily disable it by using the **"--no-pager"** flag.

Like this: `git --no-pager diff`

Answer (score 0):

Simply print the diff output to a file

```
git diff > my_file_name
```

And now simply open the file with any editor.
Here is a demo how it will look like using vim, you can see the title and teh file content.

[image]

Comment: Even better, you can pipe it: `git diff | vim -R -`

Answer (score 0):

By default git uses `less` as a pager to display output. Apparently you have something overridden here, as I remember by default it doesn't clean screen on exit. Read documentation around `core.pager` in `git help config`. And look how to provide `-X` parameter to `less` (see `man less` for other handy options).